# Cytoscape: TypeError even with the tutorial

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I would like to use [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org), so I copy-pasted their [tutorial](http://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/initialisation):

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy')
});
```

... and I got this (on the Firefox console):

```
TypeError: r is null
```

and this (on the Safari console):

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'r.className')
```

The error persists on Chrome, always indicating the line 39 of `cytoscape.min.js`.

Of course, I have an HTML `<div id="cy"></div>` element.

Why do I get this error? Also, I tried to add some nodes and they render on JSFiddle but not on the browsers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error was the following: I was trying to initialise the Cytoscape graph *before* the page was loaded, so Cytoscape could not find any `#cy` div inside the HTML.

The solution was just to wrap the initialisation in a function and call this function after the page was loaded (with `<body onload="setupMyGraph();"> ... </body>`).

Answer (score 1):

afaik, this should fix your problem

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  })
 <cytoscape stuff like adding nodes, setting style, ...>
})
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct too. I think that my answer and yours are equivalent, but apparently your solution is faster: https://jsperf.com/onload-vs-domcontentloaded